# Programmatic access to pipeline variable groups in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I wonder if I can get programmatic access (REST API, cli, program API - whatever ) to read/write variables in variable groups aka libraries in ADO pipelines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [DistributedTask/VariableGroups API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedTask/Variablegroups/Get%20Variable%20Groups?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use REST API to manage variable groups:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Examples of C# code to access REST API can be found from here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples